# How to calculate percentile difference in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say you have 2 tables.

```
Table 1 - T
Columns
City ID(Foreign keyed to C.cityid)
Completed (yes or no)
NumberOne (integer)
NumberTwo (integer)
Date (timestamp with timezone)

Table 2 - C
City ID (integer)
City Name (string)
```

For each of the cities 'A' and 'B', how do I calculate 90th percentile difference between NumberOne and NumberTwo for all completed things within the last 30 days.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT  
    100.0*(T.NumberOne - T.NumberTwo) / T.NumberTwo As PercentDiff
FROM T
JOIN C ON CityID
```

I'm new to SQL and not sure how to create one query for all of this. Do I need to use subqueries?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  100.0*(t.NumberOne - t.NumberTwo) / t.NumberTwo As PercentDiff
from T t
inner join C c
on t.[City ID] = c.[City ID]
where c.Name in ('A','B') 
and t.Completed = 'yes'
and t.Date > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: If it's 90th percentile, then I should change the 100.0 to 90.0 right? Just wanted a second opinion...Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try `ON CITYID = CITYID`  The in statement expects a Boolean expression.